# change a button's coordinates in a grid with a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-grid

[game grid interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdvJa.png)

I am doing a 15 puzzle game on wpf and xaml where you need to move the empty tile in a grid to solve the puzzle. (see the linked image for context) I want to know how I can go about changing a button's coordinates when switching it with the coordinates of the empty tile using the up,down,left,right buttons. Here below you have an example of the coordinates i am talking about,  .row and .column.

````
        <Button x:Name="Button10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="3"/>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Row or Column of your Buttons like this.

```cs
// Move up Button5 example
private void ButtonUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current Row
    int currentRow = Grid.GetRow(Button5);

    // Calculate the next Row
    int nextRow = Math.Min(Math.Max(currentRow - 1, 0), 3);

    // Change the Row
    Grid.SetRow(Button5, nextRow);
}

// Move left Button5 example
private void ButtonLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current Column
    int currentColumn = Grid.GetColumn(Button5);

    // Calculate the next Column
    int nextColumn = Math.Min(Math.Max(currentColumn - 1, 0), 3);

    // Change the Column
    Grid.SetColumn(Button5, nextColumn);
}
```

Comment: Definitely a much more solid answer than the one I wrote! I learned something reviewing this as well so thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would you go about changing the row or column of the tile we are switching the button 5 with, so it goes where the button 5 was previously without explicitly calling for the button.

Comment: You might have a position (row, column) manager that knows which button is on each position, something like @ExplodatedFaces posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the position of an element by calling it as part of the `Grid.GetRow` or `Grid.GetColumn` methods.

```
int row = Grid.GetRow(button1);
int column = Grid.GetColumn(button1);
```

It might be best to create an object type for this so you can keep track of many buttons and what their positions were even after they moved.

```
    public class position
    {
        private int row;
        private int column;
        public position(int row, int column)
        {
            this.Row = row;
            this.Column = column;
        }

        public int Row
        {
            get => row;
            set => row = value;
        }
        public int Column
        {
            get => column;
            set => column = value;
        }
    }
```

and then you can mark the current position of multiple grid items

```
position first_button = new position(Grid.GetRow(button1), Grid.GetColumn(button1));
position second_button = new position(Grid.GetRow(button2), Grid.GetColumn(button2));
```

and from there you can call these objects to move grid elements

```
Grid.SetColumn(button2, first_button.Column);
Grid.SetRow(button2, first_button.Row);
```